# Grails 2 vs Grails 3

Tags: grails

I'm rather new to grails and I'm about to start a new grails project. I'm very confused with what version to go with based on the tools not being ready to support the newest version. I've read version 3 was a complete rewrite from ground up which my gut says should be the version to go with considering the project is brand new, but I'm discovering none of the tools are ready for version 3.

I was successfully able to get version 3 up with intellij with out grails support and the same goes for ggts.

With that being said, I don't know how to run the app in ggts since grails-runapp doesn't work

with ggts, I used the following tutorial https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2015/04/10/grails-3-released-installing-gradle-and-groovy-2-4-support-in-eclipseggts/ but I've been able to figure out how to get the app to run. Does anybody know how to do this?

My questions are

1. How do I run a Grails 3 app in GGTS.
2. Is it recommended to use Grails 3 at this point or should I use Grails 2
3. If you use Grails 3, what is the recommended IDE?

With Intellij I had to run it by going to the grails-app/init project run main. Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

As of Grails 3 you don't need a special IDE To run Grails 3 application. all you need to do is to right-click on the Application class and execute to start your Grails application. To read more about IDE integration https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/introduction.html

Currently, not all plugins are upgraded to Grails 3. So if your project depends on some plugins that are not already upgraded this will be an issue. For example spring security is not upgraded yet, but there is a work around to use it.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/grails-dev-discuss/spring$20security/grails-dev-discuss/jOF0jw_BiCs/tOxd0NZpaxkJ

Finally, both Intellij community edition and GGTS supports Grails3. But if you want special grails features like GSP syntax highlighting use GGTS or IDEA Ultimate edition.

Comment: So it sounds as if it's best to stick with grails 2 for the time being. How complex is it to upgrade from 2 to 3 once 3 is a bit more solid? Would it require a complete rewrite?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new grails 3 project and move your old project to new one. see https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/upgrading.html

Comment: @CodeJunkie what did you do?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ idea 15 is out. Try that. The support for Grails 3 is built in.

Choose Grails 3 instead of Grails 1/2 in project selection.

Answer (score 1):

I have 6 projects running Grails 2 for over 1 year.
So far I have not encountered any need to upgrade them to Grails 3.

I use the latest edition of IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.2, and for the most part it works good with Grails 2.  The debugger still throws a lot of EVAL errors, but I am able to evaluate my variables in real time.

The biggest problem I've encountered so far is plugins that are not compatible with Java 1.8.  Some of the plugins still have to run in Java 1.7.

Lastly, I'd say if your project is still new, look into using NodeJs. It seems to be more popular than Grails at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I think intellij is better for development in grails from my experience.

Grails 3 will be good choice for development. there are lot more features in there
https://dzone.com/articles/whats-new-grails-3

also document site will give you clear concept about it

http://docs.grails.org/latest/

Answer (score 0):

2. Considering the fact that grails version 2 is different from grails version 3; it will be good if you start with version 3 and avoid the possibility of running into upgrade issues from 2.x to 3.x in the future
3. You can use Netbeans or Intelij. I use Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Facing a lot of issues in **Database migration in Grails 3.1.6**. Not helping at all. 
I think remaining a few days in version 2 will be beneficiary as long as version 3 stables.

Besides The GGTS support will be needed as ***Intellij IDEA 15 community edition does not support Grails***. So better back to the old versions.